# How to (or can I) resume from suspend by a command?

Tags: suspend, systemd, kde-connect

I want to do suspend and resume via KDE Connect's command function. It's possible, and I've done to do suspend, but I cannot find a way to resume via command. How to (or Can I) do so?

Comment: If the computer is sleeping how do you expect to respond to a command?

Comment: I don't know is it possible, so I added a "Can I" in the title.

Comment: As the computer is not powered off (just sleeping, not hibernating), I think there should be a way to resume it.

Comment: In hardware yes never heard of a software way to wake a sleeping machine. What do you define as the difference between sleeping and hibernating?

Comment: @David: Maybe the comment you commented is the answer: "No, that's impossible."
As I've done the unlock and lock part of the KDE Connect commands, that might be enough for me.

Comment: Could WOL - Wake On Lan - work here ? I have no experience with WOL and Suspend/Resume, so it is just a "qualified" guess.

Comment: @SorenA that was also my thought.

Comment: I used WOL a long time ago. You had to enable it in the BIOS. Then, when the network card receives a specially crafted packet, the whole OS is resumed. I used this little app on Windows: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wake_on_lan.html to wake up my Ubuntu server. More explanation on that link. It only runs on wired networks, not on WiFi.